# How xmlhttprequest objects are created, merged, and destroyed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

My background is in traditional compiled object-oriented languages such as C++ and .NET programming, and I am now dabbling into a bit of JavaScript for a new project. I was dabbling with AJAX and came upon a confusing aspect of how objects are managed by the browser.

**[Edit #2] - Change in active content scripts**

I have a practice page with three buttons which each update a `<textarea>` using `XMLHttpRequest` objects:

1. Button 1 updates TextArea1 with text content from *slowtime.php*
2. Button 2 updates TextArea2 with text content from *slowtime.php*
3. Button 3 updates TextArea3 with text content from *fasttime.php*

Where *slowtime.php* and *fasttime.php* are simple scripts which return a text/HTML page with two timestamps: one when the page loads, one after some time has elapsed.

Each of the buttons works correctly when clicked one at a time. If I click Button 2 and then Button 3 before the first request is complete, the updates still work as expected.

If I click Button 1 and then Button 2 before the first request is complete, TextArea1 and TextArea2 receive the correct values; however, the `onreadystatechange` event calls occur at the same time, i.e., the first response it late and is only processed when the second one arrives.

**Sample Code**

Website

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc(url,target)
{
var xmlhttp;
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(target).value=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>

<input type="button" value="Button 1" onClick="loadXMLDoc('slowtime.php','TextArea1')"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 2" onClick="loadXMLDoc('slowtime.php','TextArea2')"/>
<input type="button" value="Button 3" onClick="loadXMLDoc('fasttime.php','TextArea3')"/>

<div><textarea id="TextArea1"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea id="TextArea2"></textarea></div>
<div><textarea id="TextArea3"></textarea></div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP Code (*slowtime.php*)

```
<?php
     echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
     sleep(5);
     echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";
?>
```

**Questions [Revised]**

How does the browser manage the `XMLHttpRequest` objects? Pressing buttons 2 and 3 indicate that each press instantiates a new object, and each of these have independent event handlers. If the objects live past the initial function call (since their event handlers survive) when are they cleared from memory / destructed?

If the `XMLHttpRequests` are separate objects, how does sending a second request to the same URL affect the response timing of the first? Might this be a server-side issue?

Comment: In your `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` function, should you perhaps use `this.responseText` instead of `xmlhttp.responseText`?

Comment: @JoshuaD.Boyd That shouldn't do anything else as the `xmlhttp` variable is in a local scope inside the `loadXMLDoc`.

Comment: changing all references to `xmlhttp` to `this` in the `onreadystatechange` function also works, and also produces the same behavior

Comment: I guess this also depends on the browser.

Comment: This behavior shouldn't happen. A browser can send 6 simultaneous xhr requests (that is, IE6 iirc). It shouldn't have problems. And it definitely shouldn't mix different XHR objects together. Could you provide a jsfiddle with the same behavior?

Comment: @Ragnagord, I have tested the site with different browsers and included the observations in the question.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, not sure about IE6, which did not have native support for the js `xmlhttprequest` object type - it required an `ActiveXObject`.

Comment: @nicholas can you include the source code for *slowrand.php* and *fastrand.php*?

Comment: Feels like a caching issue. Could you try with `  `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", new Date(0));` just before `xmlhttp.send()`? Also, no browser should ever be "merging" requests, as stated above.

Comment: @seliopou: you lead me to find a major problem with the server-side code. for diagnostics, *slowrand* was opening and writing to file. the second *slowrand* call was attempting to open a locked file and therefore was exiting on error - long story short, using different php code to write timestamps instead, i get different results. the requests are not merged, but their timing is messed up.

Comment: @nicholas Glad I could help. Your client-side code seemed correct, and caching wasn't an issue since you were `POST`ing. That only left one last source of the problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

context to XMLHttpRequest is never deleted unless delete is explicitly called on the object. In this case: xmlhttp. You really should be tracking that var somehow and cleaning it up if you want your application to run lean and clean. Javascript was originally designed for web pages, thus it tends to let things run wild unless you prevent it yourself.

Otherwise, it is possible that once the object is no longer usable by any other functions or has any remaining call backs, the garbage collector of the browser will eliminate the object.

As for your issue with the events happening simultaneously, I can not reproduce the issue myself, which does leave me to believe you have an issue with your php configuration. Is it possible your server is not allowing multiple scripts to run at once?

Here is your example on my server, with a couple of slight changes:
http://www.seijinohki.net/test.php

Comment: Thanks for posting the code on a different test server. When I test your site in Chrome or Safari, I get the same results as rambo, above - both text areas get the same value. Meanwhile, Firefox, IE9, and Silk does not. Your page does not work at all in Maxthon mobile browser.

Comment: well after much time, ill accept this as the answer since it directly addresses the context the the requests. an interesting discussion, and goes to show, at least at present, that web development / browsers / etc. are still anything but uniform in how they execute scripts..

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser issue.

- Chrome 23&26 behave this way.
- Opera 12 doesnt
- IE 9 doesnt
- Firefox 17 doesnt

If you make the urls unique, eg `slowtime.php?1` and `slowtime.php?2` then chrome no longer behaves this way.

btw- in my test chrome updates both textareas with the same values - the values from the first request. and they both update when the first request finishes, not when the second finishes. this is surely a bug because its just plain wrong. I verified via webserver logs that the 2nd request never gets sent.

Comment: When I test with Chrome or Safari on kokorohakai's server, I see the same results you do - both text areas get the same value and are timed with the first request. Meanwhile on my test server (localhost), I get two different values, timed with the second. This leads me to believe that the answer is very complicated, indeed, and is based on both browser and server behavior.

Comment: @nicholas does your local server log indicate two requests? still, the fact that chrome only sent one request in my test indicates a bug in it(or a weird feature).